# How to combine entries but remove unnecessary duplicated data?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Hello I was wondering if there is a way of removing duplicates in array but merging the correct values together? E.g. if there was the same product with two different images, how to combine the images into a array and then remove the entry to have one entry in array

```
$cars = array(
    array(
        "id" => 22,
        "image" => "test.jpg",
        "car" => "Volvo"
    ) ,
    array(
        "car_id" => 23,
        "image" => "prototype.jpg",
        "car" => "BMW"
    ) ,
    array(
        "car_id" => 22,
        "image" => "test_1.jpg",
        "car" => "Volvo"
    ) ,
    array(
        "car_id" => 25,
        "image" => "unknown.jpg",
        "car" => "KIA"
    )
);
```

and this outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [image] => test.jpg
            [car] => Volvo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 23
            [image] => prototype.jpg
            [car] => BMW
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 22
            [image] => test_1.jpg
            [car] => Volvo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 25
            [image] => unknown.jpg
            [car] => KIA
        )

)
```

However how can I achieve the following?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [image] => Array 
                       (
                          [0] => test.jpg
                          [1] => test_1.jpg
                       )
            [car] => Volvo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 23
            [image] => prototype.jpg
            [car] => BMW
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 25
            [image] => unknown.jpg
            [car] => KIA
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for your example data could be to create a new array `$result` and use the value for car as the key. On each iteration check if the key exits. If it does not, add the current `$car` in the loop as the first value for that key.

If the key does exists, then convert the string of the image of the `$car` to an array containing that one string.

Add the already existing image string from `$result` to the new array and make the array the new value.

For example:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    if (!array_key_exists($car['car'], $result)) {
        $result[$car['car']] = $car;
        continue;
    }
    $car['image'] = (array)$car['image'];
    $car['image'][] = $result[$car["car"]]["image"];
    $result[$car['car']]['image'] = $car['image'];
}

print_r(array_values($result));
```

If you don't want the cars as the key but numbers, you could use array_values on the final array like:

```
print_r(array_values($result));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/L385a)

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test_1.jpg
                    [1] => test.jpg
                )

            [car] => Volvo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 23
            [image] => prototype.jpg
            [car] => BMW
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [car_id] => 25
            [image] => unknown.jpg
            [car] => KIA
        )

)
```